# Auto layout issue in swift code

Tags: swift, autolayout

[image: want to create UI such that]

want to create UI such that constraint should be such that the space between the two button and the distance from the side edge should be same.

I am using the following code

```
  func addConstraintsToBottomButtons()
  {
    let viewFrame = self.view.frame
    let availableWidth:CGFloat = viewFrame.width - 60
    let buttonDistance:CGFloat = availableWidth/3
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 30.0
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 30.0

    var BtnOne = UIButton()
    BtnOne.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(BtnOne)
    BtnOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    var btnTwo = UIButton()
    btnTwo.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(btnTwo)
    btnTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()


//Views to add constraints to
//Metrics for Visual Format string

    // Button One Constraint..
    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: BtnOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bottonView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: buttonDistance))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: BtnOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bottonView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: BtnOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonWidth))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: BtnOne, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonHeight))


    // Button Two Constraint...

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bottonView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -(buttonDistance)))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bottonView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonWidth))

    self.view .addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: btnTwo, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonHeight))
 }
```

Comment: is it with storyboard layout or programatically

Comment: And what's the code and question? Which version of iOS?

Comment: programatically and iOS version 8

Comment: Look at UIToolBar, it can help

Answer (score 0):

let me suggest a workaround that will do just the thing you want:
Create three views in storyboard / pull them out of the same place where you get buttons - and use them as cushions between the edges of your screen and your buttons: anchor to edges, equal width, and lower horizontal compression than the actual buttons and it should behave as desired.